# SyntaxError: missing name after . operator

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I'm stuck with a problem that i can not use YUIcompressor to minify a file, the script runs without problems, but returns the error `missing name after . operator` in the line 3 of [**this script**](http://pastebin.com/QGH12gTj):

exactly in: `"+ source.response.chars[k].name +"`

im out of ideas, the scripts seems work, and no are any problem.

Comment: I ended up here for the same error, but a different cause. YUI Compressor trips up on a Promise's catch method: https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/issues/203

Answer (score 3):

The problem are on `"+source.response.chars[k].class+"` not in `"+ source.response.chars[k].name +"`, `class` is a reserved name.